# Select by Month of a field

Tags: mysql

How can I get records from my table using month/year? I have a table like this:

```
Name - varchar
DueDate -datetime
Status -boll
```

`DueDate` is project due date, I want record corresponding to month/year, not full date, I mean record for specific month.

How can I do this in mysql?

Comment: seems that everybody else was quicker than me at typing!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Simply use [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year):

```
SELECT * FROM Project WHERE MONTH(DueDate) = 1 AND YEAR(DueDate) = 2010
```

Comment: This will not use an index if one exists on the `duedate` column.  Todd R's answer is the best choice.

Comment: For day filtering one could use `DAY()`.

Comment: Thanks! So much easier than using `from_unixtime()` on unix timestamps.

Answer (score 30):

You could use a between statement:

```
select * from Project 
  where DueDate between '2010-01-01' and '2010-02-01'
```

Comment: +1: This will use an index if one exists on the `duedate` column; the answers using MONTH & YEAR functions will not.

Comment: Careful, `BETWEEN` is *inclusive* on both ends, so this would give you records from Feb 1st, which isn't what you want. Best option is `select * from Project where DueDate between '2010-01-01' and LAST_DAY('2010-01-01')`

Comment: @SamBarnum it is inclusive, yes, but one thing you're missing is that datetime also has the time part and in case of providing only the date part (2010-01-31 in this case), you're also implicitly providing the 00:00:00 time. you're missing one whole day

Comment: @SoulReaver depends on whether the field you're searching on is DATE or DATETIME. If DATE, using LAST_DAY is safe. for DATETIME, you'd probably want to search to the last second of the month for best accuracy.

Answer (score 8):

Do not use this here recommended solution with `MONTH()` and `YEAR()`. It prevents MySQL to use index on column `DueDate` if you have one and it forces MySQL to examine all rows in table.

Instead, use `BETWEEN` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Project 
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-02-01'
```

Or another solution with IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Project 
WHERE DueDate IN ('2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', ..., '2010-01-31')
```

This two solutions allows MySQL to use index, so performance will be better.

Comment: The second one is just useless. Who would ever prefer to provide 31 dates instead of 2?!

Comment: Every function has its uses. Maybe someone needs to select from a list of dates.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Name FROM Table Where MONTH(datetime) = 1;
```

1 = January.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: what if date is "1 JAN 2010" and "2 JAN 2009". according to your query it will find both

Comment: Hmmm.. Surely he can understand that he can use YEAR, im not here to give him the answer but to guide him. i gave hem documentation for MONTH() Function, im sure he would look for YEAR(),DAY() and HOUR() :)

Comment: This will not use an index if one exists on the `duedate` column.  Todd R's answer is the best choice.

Comment: He never asked for an indexable column, he required to select all rows that have the particular month, not by creating ranges for dates although i see your point, if he used some function to generate a $min,$max range this would be more appropriate !

Answer (score 3):

it will select current year's specific month

```
SELECT * FROM Project WHERE MONTH(DueDate) = 1 AND YEAR(DueDate) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you input month format "Y-m" you can use:

`SELECT * FROM Project WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DueDate,"%Y-%m") = '2010-01'`

Comment: Can this query use an index if the DueDate col. is indexed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) for your DueDate.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * WHERE MONTH(DueDate) = '5' AND YEAR(DueDate) = '1987';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DueDate LIKE '2020-01%';
```

use in case you can substring your date data.