# Mysql date problem

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select by Month of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997364/select-by-month-of-a-field)

i want to get the data from database whose month is 7. means

My Date format is

```
    PostDate    datetime
```

now i want to query..

```
select * from tabelname where PostDate = 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to query MySQL for date objects based on month, then this may be your answer.

select * from tablename where month(PostDate) = '07';

Keep in mind this function (month()) is MySQL specific.

Comment: Is `month` sargable? Will it use an index (assuming there is an index on that table.) Or would a better solution be to do a BETWEEN type search between the 1st and the last of july?

Comment: @Lasse: No, it's not Sargable.

Comment: If you have dates from many years, then a good approach is to add another (tinyint) field which will store month and add an index on it.