# How to SELECT data month by month in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I've stored data in `MySQL` database with the date as below.

```
pageview_date
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
2015-01-07
```

How can I `SELECT` data by months ? I mean all data for January, December, November .... separately ?
How to set `WHERE` part?
I want to get last 6 months data from today by each month programmatically

Comment: Not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Do you need count of that month or all data?

Comment: If you mean getting the records with a timestamp having a specific month, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997364/select-by-month-of-a-field

Comment: If you mean that you want the results ordered by month, take a look at [ORDER BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php)

Comment: I need to get it separately. each month separately

Comment: @miuranga Just to clear some things up: Today is January 7th, so you would want December 7th, November 7th, October 7th etc.?

Comment: @Peter No, All data count of January,  December, November ect... separately each month. This is for draw a graph.

Comment: @miuranga Then you will need to do 6 queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want count of all months use below SQL

```
SELECT
    count(*) as month_count,
    MONTHNAME(pageview_date),
    YEAR(pageview_date),
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY
    MONTH(pageview_date),YEAR(pageview_date)
```

If you want data separately

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    MONTH(pageview_date) = {Month Value} AND YEAR(pageview_date) = {Year Value}
```

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE MONTH(pageview_date) = 1 AND YEAR(pageview_date) = 2014
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE MONTH(pageview_date) = 2 AND YEAR(pageview_date) = 2014
```

Comment: I like the 'if you want' parts

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ....
WHERE pageview_date >= '2014-01-01' AND pageview_date < '2014-02-01'
```

That will get you January.

This works even if pageview_date is a `datetime` or `timestamp` column.

Comment: I want to get last 6 months data from today by each month programmatically

Comment: Then run 6 queries in your programming language.

Answer (score 2):

> select * from your_table
>   where yourdate_column > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

Comment: @miuranga its gives you data from last 6 month

Comment: Thanks. but I need to get it separately. each month  separately

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE MONTHNAME(pageview_date) = 'December';
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE MONTHNAME(pageview_date) = 'April';
...
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I want to get last 6 months data from today by each month programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I think like queries will help you Please try this

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE %-$month-%;
```