# How to pass month and year in url

Tags: php

I am displaying a list of months and years from the database like this into a drop-down menu:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `b_date` FROM `summary` GROUP BY YEAR(`b_date`), MONTH(`b_date`)");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $month = date('F Y', strtotime($row['b_date']));
        echo "<option value='{$month}'>{$month}</option>";
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on a choice, it redirects to another page like:

```
mypage.com/results.php?date=
```

The problem is that I don't know what to set the value as. In the current code the url produced looks like:

```
php?date=April%202017
```

That obviously isn't ideal. And the point is that on the results page I need to show results for the month that was selected. So, I need that query string to query the database.

Comment: `When the user clicks on a choice, it redirects to another page like:`-> so you are using jquery to do that?

Comment: Frankly, I don't quite understand what you're asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this  (use `urlencode()`):-

```
$month = date('m-Y', strtotime($row['b_date']));
echo "<option value='".urlencode($month)."'>{$month}</option>";
```

Now on next page check `$_GET['date']` and see it's coming  proper or not?

if it come proper in format like `m-Y` then split it with `-` and now you get month and year separately. Use them in your query or wherever you want.

Query need to be like something:-

```
$_GET['date'] = '04-2017';

$date_array = explode('-',$_GET['date']);

$month = $date_array[0];
$year  = $date_array[1];

"SELECT * FROM summary WHERE MONTH(<you date column name>) = $month";
```

Comment: This is working as is the answer below. So, in the url I have 04-2017 which is great. Now I need to extract all records from the database for that month with my SELECT statement.

Comment: @Jonathan  now do something like this:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/2997388/4248328

Comment: That is great except I need to get the year as well. If I choose a different year it brings up all years for that month. I am guessing I need a different explode for the year

Comment: @Jonathan  see my edited answer. you will get month and year both on explode

Comment: Thank you. Still showing all years in the result instead of selected year only. Does the SQL query not need to change? I tried adding AND YEAR(`b_date`) = $year and it now works actually

Comment: yes you have to add that. if not working then try date_format of mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can put to select value something like 05-2017:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $month = date('m-Y', strtotime($row['b_date']));
    echo "<option value='{$month}'>{$month}</option>";
}
```

And then get it with `DateTime` object:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $_GET['date']);
```

And then you can format this object to any format you want:

```
$formated_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can chose another format, but I think you understand my idea.

UPD. To execute all record on this month try to use this code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $_GET['date']);
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM `summary` WHERE YEAR(`b_date`) = :year AND MONTH(`b_date`) = :month");
$stmt->bindParam(':month', $date->format('m'));
$stmt->bindParam(':year', $date->format('Y'));
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

I think its working but maybe need to fix.

Comment: This is working as is the answer above. So, in the url I have 04-2017 which is great. Now I need to extract all records from the database for that month with my SELECT statement.

Comment: This looks like PDO though, I am using mysqli

Answer (score 0):

U can format data in select (postgres, mysql...)

SELECT TO_CHAR('MM-YYYY', `b_date`) AS `formated_date` FROM `summary` GROUP BY TO_CHAR('MM-YYYY', `b_date`